# Explanation in Rokeach in regard to kissing ones wife

Tags: sexuality, parts-of-the-body, kissing, face

The Rokeach in Hilchos Niddah (see [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21522&st=&pgnum=231)) discusses the results of certain events or actions by the parents prior to conception, affecting the build or personality of the child. One case he brings is:

> "ואם מהפך יד ליד ומהפך לשונו דע כששימש אביו עם אמו נשק לאמו ויצא לשונו מפיו"

What's p'shat in the Rokeach? What does he mean exactly? What type of kissing is he referring to?

(I was by one of the Gedolei HaPoskim today in Eretz Yisrael and he had on this table a letter someone sent with 8 shailos, this was one of the shailos! The rest were more practical shailos in Halacha.)

Comment: The title is lacking.  Can you improve it a little to make it clearer what your question is about?  Also, I have no idea what your question is asking.  I think some more clarification within the question itself is in order.  (Yes, I know, you have said before that you don't like when people criticize your question without taking action to improve it - but that's what these comments are for.  I have no idea how to improve it because I just don't understand what you're asking; it is up to you to clarify it.)

Comment: @SethJ I fixed the title and adding a few words. The question is easy enough to figure out "what does he mean!" don't translate the words rather explain them in which situation, in what way, what type of kissing...Like every time the question is usually understood enough the way it is.

Comment: I know that _you_ think your question is easily understood, just as we all generally think they are.  But it's usually a good idea to take constructive criticism that is meant to help you improve the quality of your question.  If your question is confusing to one person, it is probably confusing to others as well.  Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @SethJ Thanks for pointing it out. No problem.

Answer (score 4):

My first guess is -- if a person is fidgety and anxious -- their hands and tongues can never sit still -- that means that when he was conceived, his father "kissed his mother" with his tongue out. Whether that means "french kissing" or something of a more adult nature, I have no idea.

Don't ask me what to make of this Rokeach, either. (*And as usual, for practical halacha ask your rabbi.*) Keep in mind the Talmud quotes Rabbi Yochanan ben Dahavai's litany of "this behavior in the bedroom leads to children with this disability; this behavior leads to that disability" -- and then squarely rejects his opinion as the minority.

Modesty dictates that we keep this discussion short, but for those familiar with rabbinic Hebrew and the halachic process, Rabbi Yehuda Herzl Henkin has a fantastic responsum in [*Bnei Banim* 4:18](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20023&st=&pgnum=4) addressing some of these issues.